# D6: How to create a rule with a button field to send a bulk mail of a certain node?

Tags: entities, rules, views

I want to do this with my Drupal 6 install:

1. Create content (The content type being used has a [button field](http://drupal.org/project/button_field) (link to module in case needed)
2. When a user clicks the button on the newly published node it will load a view so the user can do a search and then send a customized email (pre-confirgured) to selected users using [Views Send](http://drupal.org/project/views_send).

I have been looking everywhere and I cannot seem to find a way to get it to work using Rules. Anyone have some suggestions? This is driving me nuts!

Comment: using mimemail module?

Comment: Hi monymiza, yes I am using that and node reference and a few other modules. I still can't make it work how I want.